# How to store data locally and show and edit in input edit field in FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, spring-webflux, flutter-test, flutter-state

**I have 2 screens
(1) SETTING screen
(2) Sign in screen
when I am enter  username (TEXT EDITING FIELD)  in setting screen and after pressing the save button application navigate to sign in screen above username displayed in sign in screen and when i am back to setting screen already written username is not showed**

i want to display username on setting screen and also edit in same field where I entered username and also save the setting I entered on disk storage?

kindly help me how I am resolve the problem

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: kindly suggest any youtube link